# Maintain correct GUI scaling when using QPixmap as a rendering cache

Tags: qt, scale, qpixmap

I'm using QPixmap as a rendering cache. Which causes scaling problems when using multiple screens with different scaling factors (tested on windows).

I've written a small widget for demonstration purpose. Drawing can either be done directly or on a QPixmap that is then drawn on the device. (In the real application, the pixmap is cached to prevent unnecessary paint() calls. But that's left out here for simplicity). In case someone wants the full example: https://github.com/the-yeti/qpixmap-scaling-demo

```
void RenderWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    if (m_usePixmap) {
        QPixmap pm(width(), height());
        paint(&pm);
        QPainter(this).drawPixmap(0, 0, pm);
    } else {
        paint(this);
    }
}

void RenderWidget::paint(QPaintDevice *pd)
{
    QPainter p(pd);
    p.fillRect(0, 0, pd->width(), pd->height(), QColor(192, 192, 192));

    QFontMetrics fm = p.fontMetrics();
    int h = fm.height();
    for (int i=1; i<6; i++) {
        p.drawLine(0, i*h, width(), i*h);
    }
    p.drawText(4, fm.ascent(), m_usePixmap ? "using QPixmap draw" : "using direct draw");
    p.drawText(8, h+ fm.ascent(), QString("font pointsize: %1").arg(p.font().pointSize()));
    p.drawText(8, 2*h + fm.ascent(), QString("font height: %1").arg(h));
    p.drawText(8, 3*h + fm.ascent(), QString("physicalDpiY: %1").arg(pd->physicalDpiY()));
    p.drawText(8, 4*h + fm.ascent(), QString("logicalDpiY: %1").arg(pd->logicalDpiY()));
}
```

For demonstration, I've placed two instances of the widget side-by-side. Left is directly drawn, right uses the QPixmap.

All works fine on a single Monitor.

[image]

However, when I have multiple screens with different scalings, the results differ. The direct draw correctly adapts and does renders at the current screen resolution. The pixmap always renders at the primary screen resolution.

Window on secondary screen with 150% scaling, main screen with 100% scaling:

[image]

So far that's understandable. The Pixmap doesn't know about screens, so it's reasonable that it uses the scaling of the primary screen. My question now is:

**Is there a way to tune the scaling of the pixmap rendering?**

I feel like I should modify the `logicalDpiX/Y` of the Pixmap. But that seems to be impossible as of Qt 5.6.1.

Answer (score 2):

A possible workaround would be to rescale the font size instead of the `logicalDpiY`. At least this seems to work for fonts. Not sure if one would have to modify other painter settings as well, like linewidth.

```
void RenderWidget::paint(QPaintDevice *pd)
{
    QPainter p(pd);

    if (m_usePixmap) {
        QWidget *w = this;  // widget on which the pixmap should be drawn later on

        if (pd->logicalDpiY() != w->logicalDpiY()) {
            // workaround the scaling by adapting the font
            QFont f(p.font());
            f.setPointSizeF((f.pointSizeF() * w->logicalDpiY()) / pd->logicalDpiY());
            p.setFont(f);
        }
    }

    p.fillRect(0, 0, pd->width(), pd->height(), QColor(192, 192, 192));

    ...
}
```

As above: Window on secondary screen with 150% scaling, main screen with 100% scaling:

[image]

*Note:* updated the github repo with this code: https://github.com/the-yeti/qpixmap-scaling-demo